# Python 3 socket client sending data and C++ socket server receiving data with offset?

Tags: python, sockets, visual-c++, offset, python-3.3

I have made a small test to send an integer from a python application (client socket) to a c++ application (socket server) both are TCP stream sockets. I have also tested sending the same integer from the client socket in python to a server socket in python.

What I do is I send an array of 4 bytes (char in c++), each char has the integer shifted right (>>) like this (python syntax):

```
...
[my_int >> i & 0xff for i in (24,16,8,0)]:
...
```

The problem is that when sending from the client socket in python to the server socket in python the data "arrives ok", for instance if I send the integer 1390248303

the python server socket first prints the bytes stream received then for each byte it prints its ascii code and then I do:

```
sum([l[3-i] << 8*i for i in (3,2,1,0)])
```

to "rebuild" the integer and this is the result (which is ok):

```
RECEIVED: b'R\xdd\x81o'
82
221
129
111
RECEIVED: 1390248303
```

BUT the C++ server socket, in which I do the same but with more verbose in the code:

```
...
int sum = 0;
int term = 0;
for(int i = 3;i > -1;i--)
{
    printf("%d\n",msg[3-i]);
    term = msg[3-i];
    //if (term < 0)
    //  term = 256 + term;
    suma += term << 8*i;                
};
printf("Received: %d\n",sum);
...
```

Outputs

```
82
-35
-127
111
Received: 1373405551
```

Did you see that the 2 bytes in the middle are different to the 2 bytes in the middle corresponding to what the server socket in python outputs? Not only that but if I add 256 to them they became the same:

```
 -35 + 256 = 221
-127 + 256 = 129
```

What is the reason of this behaviour? Thanks beforehand for any hint!

Here is the code of the applications:

python client socket:

```
import socket
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(("localhost", 7000))
my_int = 1390248303
my_bytes = bytearray()        
for e in [my_int >> i & 0xff for i in (24,16,8,0)]:
    my_bytes.append(e)
print("To be sent:", my_bytes)    
client_socket.send(my_bytes)
print("Sent:", my_bytes)    
client_socket.close()
```

python server socket:

```
import socket
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(("", 7000))
server_socket.listen(5)

print("TCPServer Waiting for client on port 7000")

while 1:
    client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
    print("I got a connection from ", address)
    while 1:
        data = client_socket.recv(32)
        print("RECEIVED:",data)
        l = []
        for e in data:
            l.append(e)
            print(e)
        print("RECEIVED:",sum([l[3-i] << 8*i for i in (3,2,1,0)]))
        if (data == b''):
            break;
    break;
```

C++ server socket:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


// link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_PORT "7000"
//"27015"
#define DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH 32
//512

int main() {

    WSADATA wsaData;

    // Initialize Winsock
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if(iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    hints;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;      // Internet address family is unspecified so that either an IPv6 or IPv4 address can be returned
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;    // Requests the socket type to be a stream socket for the TCP protocol
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the local address and port to be used by the server
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    // Create a SOCKET for the server to listen for client connections
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Error at socket(): %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);

    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("bind failed: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    // To listen on a socket
    if ( listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("listen failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET ClientSocket;

    ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    // Accept a client socket
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);

    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH];
    int iSendResult;

    // receive until the client shutdown the connection
    do {
        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH, 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
        {
            char msg[DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH];
            memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
            strncpy(msg, recvbuf, iResult);         

            printf("Received: %s\n", msg);
                    //Here is where I implement the python code:
            //sum([l[3-i] << 8*i for i in (3,2,1,0)]));
            int sum = 0;
            int term = 0;
            for(int i = 3;i > -1;i--)
            {
                printf("%d\n",msg[3-i]);
                term = msg[3-i];
                //if (term < 0)
                //  term = 256 + term;
                sum += term << 8*i;             
            };
            printf("Received: %d\n",sum);

            iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);

            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();

                getchar();
                return 1;
            }

            printf("Bytes sent: %ld\n", iSendResult);
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
        {
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();

            getchar();
            return 1;
        }
    } while (iResult > 0);

    // Free the resouces
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    getchar();
    //while (true){};
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`msg[]` is declared as `char` which is not guaranteed to be [unsigned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types). Use `unsigned char`.

Both of lines

```
            printf("%d\n",msg[3-i]);
            term = msg[3-i];
```

cast to signed integer. `%d` formats to signed integer, use `%u`. `term` is declared as `int`, make it `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Ante advices, I changed the code in C++ server socket, I also changed recvbuf to unsigned char and sum from int to unsigned int for consistency (after all I am waiting to receiving unsigned chars and "rebuild" an unsigned int) but it also worked leaving both recvbuf and sum as they were. I left commented what was before.

The problem was that for representing an integer so big I was actually using an unsigned integer and the bytes that were being sent were ascii codes whose range is 0 - 255 (the same range of unsigned char) and char range is -127 - 126.

Nevertheless, sockets do not care about data types, they just send binary data so I was receiveng unsigned chars that when bein put in a char they "overflow" and go negative (technically it is because of how [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) works I think).

A few more notes about the corrected code:

1) This

```
if (term < 0)
    term = 256 + term;
```

is no longer necessary (actually I was fixing manually the issue of the overflow).

2) I had to use cast to char* (char *) in order to be able to use recv,strncpy and send which take char* as parameters not unsigned char* . This work and I think it is not hackish because both a pointer to char and a pointer to unsigned char point to a datatype with the same size in memory (8 bits). If this is wrong or could lead to unwanted or unexpected behaviour please correct me.

```
    //char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH];
    unsigned char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH];
    int iSendResult;

    // receive until the client shutdown the connection
    do {
        //iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH, 0);
        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, (char *)recvbuf, DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH, 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
        {
            //char msg[DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH];
            unsigned char msg[DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH];
            memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
            //strncpy((msg, recvbuf, iResult);  
            strncpy((char *)msg, (char *)recvbuf, iResult);         

            printf("Received: %s\n", msg);

            //sum([l[3-i] << 8*i for i in (3,2,1,0)]));
            //int sum = 0;
            unsigned int sum = 0;
            //int term = 0;
            unsigned int term = 0;
            for(int i = 3;i > -1;i--)
            {
                //printf("%d\n",msg[3-i]);
                printf("%u\n",msg[3-i]);
                term = msg[3-i];                    
                sum += term << 8*i;             
            };
            //printf("Received: %d\n",sum);
            printf("Received: %u\n",sum);

            //iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);
            iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, (char *) recvbuf, iResult, 0);
```